# Undefined reference to 'cvCreateKalman'

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv

I've been working on a simple Qt C++ OpenCV app and I want to integrate a Kalman filter.
I include:

```
opencv/cv.h;opencv/highgui.h and opencv/cxcore.h;
```

in my .pro file I have:

> INCLUDEPATH += -I/usr/include/opencv LIBS += -lopencv_core \
>   -lopencv_highgui \
>   -lopencv_imgproc

However, when I do this `CvKalman* kalman = cvCreateKalman(8,4,0);` I just get undefined reference to `cvCreateKalman` and collect2: ld returned 1 exit status. Compile output doesn't provide additional info.

I tried finding help online but Google wasn't really helpful. I also tried to include additional `OpenCV` libs like ml or object tracking but nothing happened.

It seems a bit weird to me that `CvKalman` and `cvCreateKalman` are available in the autocomplete since right after loading the original libs...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `INCLUDEPATH`, Specify your library like this,

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/opencv
```

And add the modules to LIBS vaiable like this,

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui  -lopencv_imgproc
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, but unfortunately this doesn't work; I get the same error :( 
`CvKalman* kalman = cvCreateKalman(8,4,0);` 
yelds undefined reference to `'vCreateKalman'

Comment: Did you include the module corresponding to vCreateKalman? in LIBS variable?

Comment: Just so I'm not missing this thing out - what is that module ?
`INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/opencv

LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui  -lopencv_imgproc`

`#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>`

I may be missing a lib but I don't know what that is :(

Comment: Ya...you have missed -lopecv_something.

Comment: Thanks for the help; took them one by one and found out that cvCreateKalman was contained in the 'video' lib. too bad i couldn't find this answer faster with google...
My include :
`LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_video`