# main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator

I want to compile easy programm in qt creator, but I have problems with opencv. Os- ubuntu 16.04
.pro file qt

```
LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

Main program

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

IplImage* image = 0;
IplImage* src = 0;

int main()
{
    char* filename = "Image0.jpg";
    image = cvLoadImage(filename,1);
    src = cvCloneImage(image);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What if you replace `LIBS += ...` with `PKGCONFIG += opencv`?

Comment: Since this is a `QtCreator` issue and has nothing at all to do with the `Qt` framework (not sure `Qt` is even used), I changed the tags.

Comment: PKGCONFIG += opencv didnt help. 
There is problem only with "cvLoadImage".
Program compile normal,if i have remove this comand:
   `char* filename = "Image0.jpg";
    src = cvCloneImage(image)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not linking against the OpenCV libraries correctly (or for some reason the linking is not working), the code itself is compiling.

Take a look at the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731414/undefined-reference-to-cvcreatekalman) to a similar question, that will most probably help you.

And by the way, `cvLoadImage` and `IplImage` are from the old C-API, avoid those. Use `cv::Mat img=cv::imread("img.png")`, instead.